# Can an iOS application receive a memory warning in the background?

Tags: ios, memory-management

When an application is in the background and another application is running and is requiring more memory, can the app in the background receive a memory warning? Or can it only get killed from the memory without any warning?

If it's the latter, should I manually free up memory (cache) in the "applicationDidEnterBackground" method so that there is less chance that it will get killed?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your application can receive a memory warning while in the background. Your application only gets killed immediately if the system **really needs** the memory, but it'll play nice and ask your application to return memory on its own first. If the system is satisfied it won't kill your application.

Comment: I tried generating a memory warning on the simulator (Xcode 5 - iOS 7.1) when the app is in background mode but the memory warning is triggered after the app pass to foreground mode, do I need to begin a background task on didEnterBackground?