# Core Data memory usage and Memory Warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, memory-management

I have this issue.
I have a database of images in Core Data.
I fetch all images (about 80MB) and put in an NSMutableArray.
The objects are correctly faulted:

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
self.cache = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchResults];
for (ImageCache *imageObject in self.cache) {
    NSLog(@"Is fault? %i", [imageObject isFault]);
}
```

Reading the log, I see that the objects are all correctly faulted
However, using Instruments, I see that 80MB of memory are used.
I think this is why Core Data caches it's results, and should free the memory when it's needed.
But (and this is my "problem"), if I simulate a memory warning, nothing happens!
The 80MB remains there.

Looking at instruments - allocations, the 80MB are used by many Malloc: (example)

Graph    Category   Live Bytes  # Living    # Transitory    Overall Bytes   # Overall   # Allocations (Net / Overall)
0   Malloc 176,00 KB    8,59 MB 50  57  18,39 MB    107   %0.00, %0.00
0   Malloc 200,00 KB    8,20 MB 42  460 98,05 MB    502   %0.00, %0.04
0   Malloc 168,00 KB    7,05 MB 43  19  10,17 MB    62    %0.00, %0.00

This is a link to an image of the entire Call Tree: https://www.dropbox.com/s/du1b5a5wooif4w7/Call%20Tree.png

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Maybe Core Data frees memory on `Memory Warning Level 2`? Is It possible to produce low memory crash with your scenario?

Comment: Is there any "magic method" to simulate a Memory Warning Level 2? Or "simply" I have to consume memory?

Comment: I don't know any simulation method. You should run another "heavy" app (Appstore for example), keeping your app in background and tracking console log and Instruments memory chart. The `level 2` warning will be mentioned in console - so you should look at memory chart at that moment.

Comment: Mmmmhh...but If I keep the app in background, It will be freezed, so I won't receive messages from the system, isn't it? However I tried something else. I made a cycle that begun to waste memory (a simple array of casual NSData). I increased the total memory trying various amount, (tried much times, sometimes letting iOS to kill my app), but Core Data NEVER released cache :-/ (obviously tried on a device, not on the simulator)

Comment: The app will receive memory warning messages and perform `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` callback. As for Core Data cache - looks like it's not a cache :)

Comment: Mmmhh...at this link the docs says that the memory warning is not sent to sospended apps: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html  "When the system dispatches a low-memory warning to your app, respond immediately. iOS notifies all running apps whenever the amount of free memory dips below a safe threshold. (It does not notify suspended apps."

Comment: In my practice when the app is in background it receives memory warning. Same answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641194/can-an-ios-application-receive-a-memory-warning-in-the-background

Comment: Only if you start a background task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078090/not-getting-didreceivememorywarning-am-i-suspended ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I've understood why it happens. When you make a fetch request for an entity, even if the faulting is enabled, ALL DATA of that entity are loaded into memory. Including big binary data.
You can solve this using many methods:

1- setting this on your `NSFetchRequest`: `[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];`
setting NO, the data are not loaded into the cache immediately, but only upon request (when you access the property and the fault is fired)
But this have a "problem". Even if you try to fault again the propery (because you don't need it immediately and want to free the memory, using `[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];`), the memory is not freed. The cache stay alive until the managedObjectContext is reset.

This is better:

2- you can split your data into separate entities. In my case I had only 2 properties: an url and image data. I splitted the data into 2 entities with a 1:1 relationship: imagecache and imagedata.
Made a fetchRequest for all the row of the "imagecache" entity (with the url property), and like the previous solution no memory was cached. The propery imagecache.relationship.image was correctly faulted. Accessing this property caused the fault to fire and the cache to be filled.
But in this case, doing `[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];` on the "imagecache" object (the "father" object), resulted in immediately freeing the cache and the memory, faulting again imagecache.relationship.image property. Attention: Don't do on the "child" object, if you do `[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:object.relationship mergeChanges:NO]`, for some reason the cache is not freed. I think this is why you traverse the relationship.

3- I said this was mainly an academic question, the real "all day" solution (better performance and less headache) for this issues is to avoid saving big data inside core data database. You can save your data as files and store only a reference (filepath) or, with iOS 5 you have the possibility to set "use external storage" on any "Data" property inside your core data model. This will do all the work for you.

Comment: Hey, I am just wondering if you ever found any other solutions to this problem.  Unfortunately, I dont have any big NSData memory objects that I can use solution 3 for.  Rather I have hundreds of thousands of objects that are displayed as annotations on the map.  I fetch in batches so I make sure that if the device doesnt have enough memory I can limit how much data is displayed. But when I get a memory warning and call refreshObject:mergeChanges: memory is not affected as you mentioned, and I end up getting a memory crash.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load the less objects into memory in batch.

memory released by coredata happens behind the scenes and you don't have to program for it; the bad news is that it happens behind the scenes and thus can 'magically' chew up memory.

Ways around it are many; for example, use a predicate to only select the rows you absolutely must need; don't do a general call to fetch everything and then go through the list one by one. More than likely you will crash when you do the general call and CoreData attempts to load all objects.

Comment: Yes, the first solution I applied was to fetch only the data I needed. This is mainly an "academic" question. The documentation is clear about this, the cache management is made by Core Data and all happens behind the scene, but it even says that in case of low memory, the memory is free. I expected to see a decrease of the memory used by core data after a memory warning. Not seeing this, I was thinking there was something wrong in my code...! I'd like to see "with my eyes" Core Data freeing memory in low memory situation :-)

Comment: just an update: I tried to occupy memory (a simple loop allocating some NSData instances), but Core Data NEVER freed up memory (I tried a lot of times, allocating 100MB of NSData, then 200, then 300...until the app crashed). It seems that it caches all the data of the fetchrequest without freeing it, NEVER! I know that I can use other approaches to reach my scope, but it seems strange. What is the meaning of the faulting properties if they continues to use ram?