# NSFetchRequest memory problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management

I've posted similar questions about different things relating to this, but have been struggling with this for about a week now, to no avail. It all comes down to this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *oldFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *oldEntryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Media"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:oldContext];
        [oldFetchRequest setEntity:oldEntryEntity];
        [oldFetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
        NSArray *medias = [oldContext executeFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:&error];

    int i = 0;

    int count = [oldContext countForFetchRequest:oldFetchRequest error:nil];

    NSLog(@"count: %i", count);

    while (i < count) {
        @autoreleasepool {
        NSManagedObject *media = [medias objectAtIndex:i];

            [oldContext refreshObject:media mergeChanges:NO];

        NSLog(@"i: %i", i);
        i++;
        }
    }
```

Count should be reaching about 250, the amount of `media` items. It actually reaches about 100 before the app runs out of memory and crashes. It builds up more and more memory every time this code is run, presumably as each `media` contains a number of NSData attributes, including a large one. Instruments shows memory increasing every time the code is run.

`@autoreleasepool` and `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` I added to try and fix this problem, but they haven't worked.

What i'm trying to do is move all of the items from this store into a new one manually, as standard migration doesn't work with large data. This is the starting point.

Comment: is your code crashing without migrating? As is in this listing?

Comment: Yes, migration code is all taken out. All the code we're left with is the code above. I haven't commented any code out or hidden any.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295415/core-data-memory-usage-and-memory-warning See LombaX solutions, may be it help

Comment: This worked, but at the next line i'd put in, `[media valueForKey:@"originalImage"];` it crashes.

Comment: Although his mention of resetting the MOC did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For each `media` you are allocating a new instance of `NSManagedObject`. Instead, you could define one instance of `media` and reuse that.

Also, I believe that you could actually use a `NSFetchedResultsController` which is optimized for iterating through a set of fetch results and has all kinds of behind the scenes memory optimizations.

You could then simply iterate like this:

```
for (id object in _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)
```

I think both these suggestions should reduce the memory footprint significantly.

Comment: I've tried doing it with NSFetchedResultsController, to the same result. Any additional techniques I could try in relation to NSFetchedResultsController to keep the memory from increasing?